# Изменение массива JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Приходит массив в виде:

```
tagsList: [
  0: "horm"
  1: "MENEGHELLO PAOLELLI ASSOCIATI"
  2: "Sideboards"
  3: "Lacquered Sideboards"
  4: "Contemporary Style Sideboards"
  5: "Sideboards with doors"
];
```

Как преобразовать этот массив в другой вид через JavaScript?

```
tagsList: [
   {
     id: 0,
     text: "horm"
   }
   {
     id: 1,
     text: "MENEGHELLO PAOLELLI ASSOCIATI"
   }
   {
     id: 2,
     text: "Sideboards"
   }
   {
     id: 3,
     text: "Lacquered Sideboards"
   }
   {
     id: 4,
     text: "Contemporary Style Sideboards"
   }
   {
     id: 4,
     text: "Sideboards with doors"
   }
];
```

Через `array.map((item, index) => [{id: index, text: item}])`
без `[]` оно выдает ошибку. Приходит такой ответ:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что ето за вид масива такой ? `0: "horm"` это чтоли свойство ? или все же это элемент 0 масива со значением `"horm"` ?

Comment: это элемент массива 0 со значением "horm"

Comment: ну вам уже дали ответ на ваш вопрос, но на будущее массивы в js выглядят так : `var a = ["1", "2", "3"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вызвать у массива функцию [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) и в колбэке возвращать объекты, например

```
array.map((item, index) => {id: index, text: item})
```

Comment: Обновил, приходит немного не тот ответ что надо(

Comment: `{id: index, text: item}` измените на `{return {id: index, text: item};}`

Comment: Спасибо большое)